# How to add textboxes to table when button is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add a new cell and a TextBox into it when a button is clicked.  But when I click the button  in the current row, its cell and TextBox are removed and new ones are added.

**Markup:**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlForTextBoxes" runat="server">
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNumbers" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="143px">
        <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>`enter code here`
    <asp:Table ID="myActualTable" runat="server">
    </asp:Table>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="cmdAddTextBox" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="cmdAddTextBox_Click" />
</div>
</form>
```

**Code:**

```
protected void cmdAddTextBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TableRow myRow = new TableRow();
    myRow.ID = "row" + ddlNumbers.SelectedValue.ToString();
    TableCell myCell = new TableCell();
    myCell.ID = "cell" + ddlNumbers.SelectedValue.ToString();
    TextBox myTextBox = new TextBox();
    myTextBox.ID = "txt" + ddlNumbers.SelectedValue.ToString();
    myTextBox.Text = "TextBox number " + ddlNumbers.SelectedValue.ToString();
    myCell.Controls.Add(myTextBox);
    myRow.Cells.Add(myCell);
    myActualTable.Rows.Add(myRow);

    myTextBox.Dispose();
    myCell.Dispose();
    myRow.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: I think you could make your live a lot easier if you'd replace your custom built table by control like [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid) or [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4w7ya1ts) which offer ready-to-use functionality for adding, deleting and editing rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because old textbox and cell aren't presented on markup. As you know every postback page object is created, and it doesn't know about last changes on page.
There is a workaround.
In page load event you have to check, if this is postback already, then check your viewstate, or some hidden field counter with previous textbox and cells cound and recreate them again. Better specify names and id, which were specified last time, to allow viewstate recover values.
Only after that you can create new onem without loss of previous.

Comment: Thank you. I will also have  CheckBoxList in my page, I will use this.

Comment: U r wellcome, if it works for you, don't forget to mark as answer.